# How to Calculate the sum in nested JSON using Underscore JS

Tags: javascript, json, math, underscore.js

I am getting as a JSON response from an API.  The main goal I need to achieve is to calculate the sum of all the #'s in the objects.  I would like to use underscore to do this for simplicity, but I cannot understand how I would achieve this.

This is my response.

```
 [{
    "data": {          
            "row": [{
                "col": ["2015-02-10", "item1", "1"]
            }, {
                "col": ["2015-02-11", "item2", "1504"]
            }, {
                "col": ["2015-02-12", "item3", "66"]
            }, {
                "col": ["2015-02-13", "item4", "336"]
            }, {
                "col": ["2015-02-14", "item5", "19"]
            }, {
                "col": ["2015-02-15", "item6", "210"]
            }, {
                "col": ["2015-02-16", "item7", "36"]
            }, {
                "col": ["2015-02-17", "item8", "1742"]
            }, {
                "col": ["2015-02-18", "imem9", "61"]
            }, {
                "col": ["2015-02-19", "item10", "22"]
            }]
        }
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use Underscore for this, just group/reduce it down and sum it up.

```
var groups = _(items).groupBy(function(o) {
    return o.col[1];
});

var sum2 = {};
_.each(groups, function(group, key) {
  sum2[key] = _.reduce(group, function(memo, item) {
    return memo + (parseInt(item.col[2]) || 0);
  }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need underscore for this - you can do it with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which is one of the `_`-style functions that JavaScript provides:

```
var total = input[0].data.row.reduce(function (sum, element) {
    return sum + (+element.col[2]) 
}, 0);
```

I've assumed that the numbers you want to sum are the third element in each `col` array, e.g. `22` for `["2015-02-19", "item10", "22"]`.